# Does spatialite/mysql support 3D point?

Tags: mysql, database, spatialite

Recently, I was studying spatialite.I can write 2D data(like this:POINT(1 1)) into the spatial data table,but I can't write 3D data(like this:POINT(1 1 1) ) into the spatial data table.
 Who can tell me spatialite whether support 3D? If support ,how can I write a 3D data?

Comment: No, spatial indexes are implemented as r-trees, which are inherently 2 dimensional (they sort objects based on the rectangle the points of the object lie in), so if you need a 3rd dimension, you have to implement it in some other way (e.g. store z or the point (x,z) in a second column).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Spatialite supports 3D geometries](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/SpatiaLite-Geometries-Addendum.pdf) (actually 2.5D geometries).

On why it does not work for you, probably your geometry column is not defined as `XYZ`. You can check geometry metadata with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM geometry_columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add points with three 3 dimensions you have to use the correct WKT expression: `POINTZ(x,y,z)`.

(see also: https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/wkt-wkb.html)

You also have to make sure, that you geometry column is correctly defined as XYZ column. (see functions: `Dimension` `CoordDimension` `Is3D`). `GeometryType` should therefore return `POINTZ`

(see also: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html)