# How to store 3D points in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vector, 3d, geometry

I am building a table to store the following 3D vectors:

> accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, gravity, linear and Orientation.

My first attempt was to build every magnitude as float, but it has too many fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

`acc_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`acc_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`acc_z` float DEFAULT NULL,

`gyr_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`gyr_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`gyr_z` float DEFAULT NULL,

`mag_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`mag_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`mag_z` float DEFAULT NULL,

`gra_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`gra_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`gra_z` float DEFAULT NULL,

`mov_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`mov_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`mov_z` float DEFAULT NULL,

`ang_x` float DEFAULT NULL,
`ang_y` float DEFAULT NULL,
`ang_z` float DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Is there any way to store each vector in a single 3D field like the following expected result?

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`acc` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
`gyr` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
`mag` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
`gra` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
`mov` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
`ang` POINTZ DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

then I could update a value something like this?:

```
UPDATE `table` SET acc=MAKE_POINTZ(1.1,2.2,3.3)
```

It seems like 3D points are available in MySQL, but I can't find how to work with them.

Comment: I would be tempted to have a separate table, with a column for entity (source_table_id), a column for attribute (accelerometer, gyroscope, etc) and a column for each dimension (x,y,z). I would form a composite PK on (entity,attribute) for this table.

Comment: can you search for `pointz` or `geometry` datatype in mysql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992529/does-spatialite-mysql-support-3d-point

Comment: @JitendraYadav I have read that topic before but I was not able to build a table capable of accepting that data, if you know how to do it I would appreciate your help.